# Async script not caching in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, caching

So I this issue that I have a big javascript file that I want to cache. The problem is that for some reason chrome just wont cache the file FF works perfectly.

Response headers

```
Cache-Control:max-age=300
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Type:application/javascript
Date:Wed, 15 Nov 2017 07:34:18 GMT
Expires:Wed, 15 Nov 2017 07:39:19
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=97
Pragma:cache
Server:Apache/2.4.25 (Unix) PHP/5.6.30 LibreSSL/2.2.7
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
User-Cache-Control:max-age=300
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.6.30
```

request headers

```
 Accept:*/*
 Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
 Accept-Language:fi-FI,fi;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
 Connection:keep-alive
```

Script is called from header with

`<script async src='/resource'></script>`

Any ideas what could be the issue?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I'm having the exact same problem!